# How to save GeoPoint in Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in the database UI I can create a field with the type `geopoint`. After providing values, it looks something like this:

```
location: [1° N, 1° E]
```

I'm trying to save this to the DB via client side SDK (web).
Based on Twitter Feedback I tried GeoJSON, Coords Array and Coords Object:

```
location: [1, 2];
location: {
    latitude: 1,
    longitude: 2,
};
location: {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
    }
}
```

None of which resulted in the geopoint type in the database. They're just saved as Objects/Arrays.

How to save GeoPoint in Firebase Cloud Firestore via the Web SDK?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The Firestore SDKs include a [`GeoPoint class`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint), so you would have to save locations like this:

```
{
  location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
}
```

Comment: What did you import to get the GeoPoint class? I tried firebase and firebase/app but no go. I am in a firebase-admin app.

Comment: @neonguru - have you updated to the latest admin SDK? It should be in there https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.GeoPoint

Comment: @Scarygami - thanks, that explains it. I had the latest, but I needed to use the import variable from firebase-admin. Thanks again! WebStorm auto used it from firebase/app.

Comment: As of now, the `firebase-admin` isn't needed; it works great just with `firebase`

Comment: Works like Gem!

Comment: I use geopoint directly by importing `import GeoPoint = admin.firestore.GeoPoint;`

Comment: Additionally, in React Native you import `import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'`

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.

Answer (score 9):

I struggled to find out the right import/require. This is what worked for me !!

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
//other code ....

//assigning value to myLocation attribute
let newObject = {
    otherAttribute:"otherAttributeValue",
    myLocation: new firebaseAdmin.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude,longitude)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
{
  location:GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

VERSION 9 Firestore

```
import { GeoPoint} from "firebase/firestore";
const dataDocument = {
 tienda: new GeoPoint(latitude: number, longitude: number),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In typescript, you can use below code for `firebase-admin` sdk,

```js
import { GeoPoint } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
```

this is for `"firebase-admin": "11.2.0"` library version.

Also ensure that your, `latitude` must be within `[-90, 90]` inclusive while `longitude` must be within `[-180, 180]` inclusive. Otherwise firebase sdk will throw `Value for argument \"longitude\" must be within [-180, 180] inclusive, but was: 230`

In case of web SDK, simply update the import as follow

```js
import { GeoPoint } from "firebase/firestore";
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP using "google/cloud-firestore" package

you have to use this class `Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint`

example:

```
<?php

$geoPoint = new \Google\Cloud\Core\GeoPoint($latitude , $longitude);
$data = ['geopoint' => $geoPoint];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 GeoFirePoint geoFirePoint = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: lng);
    _firestore
        .collection('locations')
        .add({'name': 'random name', 'position': geoFirePoint.data}).then((_) {
      print('added ${geoFirePoint.hash} successfully');
    });
```