# How to create location-based timelines with Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-application

So basically I am trying to create a user timeline that shows all posts within a certain radius of the user while also ordering them by the number of favorites they have as well as some other filters. I’m currently querying with:

```
Db.collection(x).whereField(X, isEqualTo: Y).whereField(W, areayContains: [Z]).order(...).getDocuments()
```

And it works EXCEPT I want to also only get the posts that fall within some distance of the user location. I could do this with a range filter and a geo hash on the posts (which they have along with lat and long) except Firestore doesn’t allow for range filters on fields that are different from the count fields. I’m at a loss how to get this functionality while preserving my use of Firestore. Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are some alternatives to variables and ways of using geolocation with Firestore, so you can use the geolocation of the user, to bring the posts based on their location.

I would recommend you to take a look at the following articles, on how to use GeoPoint and GeoQueries with Firestore, to work with locations.

- [GeoPoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint)
- [Realtime GeoQueries with Firestore](https://fireship.io/lessons/geolocation-query-in-firestore-realtime/)

This article and post from the Community provide some options and configuration on how to achieve the use of location with the Firestore, which I think would help you.

- [Nearby Location Queries with Cloud Firestore](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/nearby-location-queries-with-cloud-firestore-e7f4a2f18f9d)
- [How to save GeoPoint in Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603691/how-to-save-geopoint-in-firebase-cloud-firestore)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: This is good stuff, however do you know of any methods for compounding a geopoint/hash query with another field? Like querying on .range(hash>X).range(hash<Y).orderBy(someOtherField). I know Firestore doesn't strictly support but I'm trying to come up with a solution.

Comment: Hi @NoahOmdal unfortunately, I don't know of any other method. As you mentioned, it's not supported by Firestore, so, I wouldn't recommend you to use other methods. Anyway, in case you think this would improve Firestore, I would recommend you to raise a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) with Google.