# json format for geopoint in firestore document

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints, geofirestore

I am able to save the below json data to the firestore database successfully through node.  I want to save the 'GeoPoint' to the firestore database in the json format, which I am not able to figure out how should I write in the json file below.

```
 [ {     "itemID": "MOMOS_V_101",   
         "itemName": "Sangai Momos",   
         "itemPriceHalf": 70,   
         "itemPriceFull": 130,    
         "hasImage": false,     
         "itemCategory": "momos_v",   
         "itemType": "v"  
  } ]
```

Please provide the format how the GeoPoint should be there in the json file to be stored in the firestore database.

Code To Upload bulk JSON Files to firestore database

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "YOUR_PROJECT_LINK"
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "files");

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
  }

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

    var menu = require("./files/" + file);

    menu.forEach(function(obj) {
      firestore
        .collection(file.substring(0, lastDotIndex))
        .doc(obj.itemID)
        .set(obj)
        .then(function(docRef) {
          console.log("Document written");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

The complete code to write the json files is available at this link here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n_O_iKJWM5tR3HK07Glq6d65XAezEKLf/view

Comment: hope you are looking for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603691/how-to-save-geopoint-in-firebase-cloud-firestore

Comment: @MuthuThavamani sorry it did not resolve the purpose, it is saving the geopoint coordinates in either map or array datatype and not in the required datatype of `GeoPoint`

Comment: In Firestore, `GeoPoint` is an object and you could access like map.

Comment: @MuthuThavamani  I am using this method to upload bulk data in firestore database https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n_O_iKJWM5tR3HK07Glq6d65XAezEKLf/view

Comment: @MuthuThavamani video link is here for the same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg2_VFFcAI8

Comment: now, I got it! could you please update the file parsing and firstore write code? it will add more clarity for other viewers on what you tried so far..

Comment: @MuthuThavamani added the link with main part of the code in the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's consider your `Json` has geopoint field like below,

```json
{     
     "itemID": "MOMOS_V_101",   
     "itemName": "Sangai Momos",   
     "itemPriceHalf": 70,   
     "itemPriceFull": 130,    
     "hasImage": false,     
     "itemCategory": "momos_v",   
     "itemType": "v",
     "geopoint": {
         "lat": 1,
         "long": 1
     }
}
```

to parse this as Firestore Geopoint, you have to change your iterator like below

```js
menu.forEach(function(obj) {
      obj.geopoint = new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(obj.geopoint.lat, obj.geopoint.long);

      firestore
        .collection(file.substring(0, lastDotIndex))
        .doc(obj.itemID)
        .set(obj)
        .then(function(docRef) {
          console.log("Document written");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    });
```

The above parser modifies the `geopoint` map field into Firestore `Geopoint` before write.

Comment: I tried it but it is giving me error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined` at `obj.geopoint.lat`

Comment: it means, you don't have a map field `geopoint` in your json. like one in my answer, "geopoint": {
   "lat": 1,
   "long": 1
}

Comment: ok let me see into that, I think I need to add it to every file and every document

Comment: Yes, it worked after the correction thanks