# Unable to add data to Firestore Database

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to put user info to Firestore Database, but it this is not working as I expected.

I installed required packages including cloud_firestore.

I used this code for adding users data to database.

```
try {
  setState(() {
    _isEntering = true;
  });
  if (_isLogin) {
    var userCredentials = await _firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _enteredEmail, password: _enteredPassword);
  } else {
    var userCredentials = await _firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _enteredEmail, password: _enteredPassword);
    var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("profile_images")
        .child("${userCredentials.user!.uid}.jpg");
    storageRef.putFile(_selectedImage!);
    var profileImageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(userCredentials.user!.uid).set({
       "username":"will be given..",
       "email":_enteredEmail,
       "profile_image_url":profileImageUrl
     });


  }
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == "email-already-in-use") {}
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(e.message ?? "Authentication failed"),
    ),
  );
  setState(() {
    _isEntering = false;
  });
}
```

Also, I tried to use the same approach as said in official Firestore wesite. [text](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?hl=en&authuser=0)

```
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


    final user = <String, dynamic>{
      "username":"will be given..",
       "email":_enteredEmail,
       "profile_image_url":profileImageUrl
    };

    // Add a new document with a generated ID
    db.collection("users").add(user).then((DocumentReference doc) =>
        print('DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${doc.id}'));
  }
```

I am not sure what is causing to this problem.
I have looked some questions which have partially same problems.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633237/how-to-add-json-data-to-firestore-database)
But again the reason is still unknown.
If anyone knows something please help to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I discovered the issue. In my project, when I was adding my profile image to Firebase Storage, I realized that I forgot to include the await keyword before the putFile operation. This mistake prevented the code from properly uploading the image to the storage.

```
    var userCredentials = await _firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: _enteredEmail, password: _enteredPassword);

    var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("profile_images")
        .child("${userCredentials.user!.uid}.jpg");
    storageRef.putFile(_selectedImage!);

    var profileImageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

Updated code:
var userCredentials = await _firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: _enteredEmail, password: _enteredPassword);

```
    var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("profile_images")
        .child("${userCredentials.user!.uid}.jpg");
    await storageRef.putFile(_selectedImage!);

    var profileImageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

By using await when calling putFile, the code will wait for the upload operation to complete before moving to the next line.